# Type macro's name in text editor to run it, Is such a thing even possible?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, macros

Atm, I'm notepad++ user working mostly on Javascript. And I have a lot of commands that I want to bind to macros. Remember all hotkeys is hard and unpleasant thing. So I wonder is it's possible to let say type macro name and press some button (before or\and after) to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible to type macro name and run. You need dialog "Run macro mult times" and there select needed macro, not type it.